# How do I find the $Z$ value and calculate the $P$?

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

**Please DO NOT answer the question, as I just need the right formulas in the form of plugging the numbers from the word problem into it. I struggle with this. And I need to find what the percentage is of the money she makes compared to other babysitters. Please help.**

Your babysitter claims that she is underpaid given the current market. Her hourly wage is $12$ per hour. The normal average is $14$ per hour with a standard deviation of $1.9$. Calculate the $Z$ score and use the table to find the standard normal probability. Based on your findings, should you give her a raise? Explain your reasoning as to why or why not.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a particular value $x$, and you want to standardize it,
you calculate its $z$ score
$$z_{\text{score}} = \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$$
where $\mu$ is the population average and $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation.

Depending on the table you use, the $z$ score will help you find the area under the curve of a standard normal distribution.

For example, if your table is defined as "area to the left", then
the value of the table $\Phi(z_\text{sc})$ will give the area under the standard normal curve from $-\infty$ to $z_{\text{sc}}$. This area is a value in $(0,1)$ and can be interpreted as a percentage.

Comment: Thank you, that is what i needed confirmed! Do I just find the P value by looking at a chart once I have found Z?

Comment: @user296473 I read your mind :P I think I was answering that also. Take a look now.

Comment: I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: @user296473 Sure, no problem. Consider upvoting and giving a check mark to answers that you found useful, past and for future reference.

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that. I'll navigate the site and I will try my best.

Comment: @user296473 Next to the response to your questions, there are up/down arrows. Those are up/down votes. Below the down vote is a check mark. If you accept someone's answer, then click that check mark. It will then turn green. Thank so much.

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms (somewhat), the standard score formula (or $z$-score) is $$z := \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma},$$ where $\mu$ is the (population/sample) mean, $\sigma$ is the (population/sample) standard deviation, and $x$ (called the score) is the value you want to calculate the *standard* score for. Once you obtain the value, $z$, you can look it up in [this table](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~morris/MAT135A/materials/standardnormaltable.pdf) to find what you call $P$ in your question (it's actually the area under the standard normal distribution curve from $-\infty$ to $z$ according to this table, that is, $P(Z\leq z)$ where $Z\sim \text{Normal}(0,1)$).